# Flow understanding A type based on another type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I was going throgh the flow documentation ( [**HERE**](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/mixed/) ) and came across the following lines of code:

```
function identity<T>(value: T): T {
  return value;
}
```

The above code is used to illustrate an example for **A type based on another type**. I don't quite understand the usage and how would this be practically applicable, can somebody please shed some light on this with a practical/real life example.

Comment: Not sure if you are using Typescript, but [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) article explains well.

Comment: @Prachi this is not typescript, but flow . Thanks though

Answer (score 2):

These are [Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html).

So if you compile that code in javascript it would look something like

```
function identity(arg) {
    return arg;
}
```

So basically when you pass an argument to this function it will return you the value of same type.

From above [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html)

[image]